# Return same array (zval) as passed in to a function

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I tried to create a new function in my extension which takes an `array` as parameter adds an entry to **that** same instance of the array and returns that instance again.

So this is the code so far:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(make_array)
{
        // array_init(return_value); // Also Tried to transform default NULL to array

        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a", &return_value) == FAILURE) {
                RETURN_FALSE;
        }

        add_assoc_long(return_value, "answer", 42);

        return;
}
```

But I only get `NULL` as return value or if I uncomment `array_init(return_value);` the `return_value` is an empty array.

So why is that behavior? And what did I understand wrong?

Comment: The `array_init(return_value);` is definitely required ;-)

Comment: @Ja͢ck Agree with that but why do I get an empty array as return value? Even if copy the paramter array to `return_value` does not work... I add a value `42` to the initalized array but it stays empty...

Comment: Have you tried using a regular `zval *` in your ZPP and then use `RETVAL_ZVAL`?

Comment: Okay that works great. Thx once again... the question stays: why can't I do that directly over the `return_value` ?

Comment: The `return_value` is somewhat special; for one, it's already initialised by the time your function body runs. I did a quick scan across the whole project and this is never done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `return_value` directly as part of a ZPP argument is typically not done (actually, never); it's commonly done by introducing a regular `zval *` container and then RETURN_ZVAL or RETVAL_ZVAL macro is used:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(make_array)
{
    zval *arr;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a", &arr) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    add_assoc_long(arr, "answer", 42);
    RETURN_ZVAL(arr, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I used `RETVAL_ZVAL` instead of like you `RETURN_ZVAL()` and the result is the same. What's the difference between those 2 macros? I also managed to modify the passed in array and keep this instance by setting the `cpy` param to `0` instead to `1` for the `RETURN_ZVAL()` macro.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER `RETVAL_ZVAL` just sets the return value, it doesn't actually return from the function ... they do the same if they're the last statement of course :)

Comment: Yeah, the `copy` parameter was somewhat intentional I guess ... I don't typically like functions that return a reference to what's passed in ... and with copy-on-write, there shouldn't really be that much difference.